# How can I test a switch case that depends on a parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I have this:

```
  const renderComponents = () => {
    switch (selectedService) {
      case 'otherservices':
        return <SoftLayerCancellationRequests />;
      case 'dedicatedhosts':
        return <GetDedicatedHostsCancellations />;
      case 'virtualguestsservers':
        return <SoftLayerGetVirtualGuests />;
      case 'baremetalservers':
        return <GetBareMetalServersCancellations />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };
```

Which at the end is called on the `return` statement of the component:

```
return (
    <>
      <Header pageTitle={t('cancellations.header')} />

            {accountId ? (
              <>
                <TableToolbarComp />
                {renderComponents()}
              </>
            ) : (
              <UpgradeMessage />
            )}

    </>
  );
```

And the `selectedService` parameter is coming from a store:

```
export default compose(
  connect(store => ({
    accountId: store.global.softlayerAccountId,
    selectedService: store.cancellations.selectedService,
  })),
  translate(),
  hot(module),
)(Cancellations);
```

What can I do to test that switch case?

Answer (score 0):

The function under `renderComponents` should accept `selectedService` as a parameter:

```
const renderComponents = (selectedService) => {
  switch (selectedService) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

By not relying on a closure, the function becomes pure and is way easier to unit test :

```
it('renders a SoftLayerCancellationRequests when passed "otherservices" as parameter', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(renderComponents('otherservices'));
  expect(wrapper.find(SoftLayerCancellationRequests)).toHaveLength(1);
})
```

Yet, I see little value in such tests. This is because the function basically acts as a simple map :

```
const serviceToComponent : {
  otherservices: SoftLayerCancellationRequests,
  dedicatedhosts: GetDedicatedHostsCancellations,
  virtualguestsservers: SoftLayerGetVirtualGuests,
  baremetalservers: GetBareMetalServersCancellations
}
```

which seems a bit dull to test.

A more meaningful test would be to test the behaviors of the component that uses such a mapping.

Comment: Honestly I didn't get the test you wrote above. The first part where you declare `const renderComponents` is that part of the test or you are mentioning it as a part of the component? Because I don't see how to call this then `const wrapper = shallow(renderComponents('otherservices'));`. And the last part, what is that?

Comment: Ok, so your own declaration `renderComponents` lives in the render function ? If so, I would advice to extract it and export it separately, so you can access it in your test (again, if you think testing the function separately is relevant). Is it OK, or should I clarify more ?

Comment: To answer your second question, if by "the last part" you mean the `toHaveLength(1)` function call, it is part of the [`Jest` API](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavelengthnumber) to make assertions on an array.